# Changing text when clicking radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code listed a number of times on the same page and I want to be able to display the **data-name** value in the foo-title span element when a radio button is clicked. The problem is that because **.foo-title span** is in the DOM several times the text is updating everywhere and not in the 1 place. I have tried several methods like .parent() .closest . prev() but cant figure it out.

The labels are styled with a background image and the text is hidden which is why I want to do the above to show the users some text information for accessibility reasons.

#### HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <p class="foo-title">
    <span></span>
  </p>

  <ul class="foo-container-list">
    <li class="foo-list-item">
      <input class="foo-input" data-name="red" id="foo_id_1" name="foo_id" type="radio" value="1">
      <label for="foo_id_1">red</label>
    </li>
    <li class="foo-list-item">
       <input class="foo-input" data-name="green" id="foo_id_2" name="foo_id" type="radio" value="2">
       <label for="foo_id_2">green</label>
    </li>
    <li class="foo-list-item">
       <input class="foo-input" data-name="blue" id="foo_id_3" name="foo_id" type="radio" value="3">
       <label for="foo_id_3">blue</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
fooBar.updateFooName = function(foo) {
  var fooName = foo.data('name');
  if (fooName) {
    $('.foo-title span').text(fooName);
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name=foo_id]:radio").change(function() {
    fooBar.updateFooName($(this));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fooBar.updateFooName = function() {
  var fooName = $(this).data('name');
  if (fooName) {
    $(this).closest('[class^="col-sm"]').find('.foo-title span').text(fooName);
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name=foo_id]:radio").change(fooBar.updateFooName);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6uoefnd/)